# Changing color of cell at specific 'coordinate'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table with cells they are each 'labeled' with a coordinate by [row,column]. For example, the first cell is [0,0]. I want a specific coordinate of the table to change color. I can get it to change color by clicking on it right now.

There should be a variable that is equal to an array. Let's say [2,2] for example. The cell at [2,2] should turn to a different color.

Code I have so far:

```js
function generateGrid( rows, cols ) {
    var grid = "<table>";
    for ( row = 1; row <= rows; row++ ) {
        grid += "<tr>"; 
        for ( col = 1; col <= cols; col++ ) {      
            grid += "<td></td>";
        }
        grid += "</tr>"; 
    }
    return grid;
}

$( "#tableContainer" ).append( generateGrid( 5, 5) );

$( "td" ).click(function() {
    var index = $( "td" ).index( this );
    var row = Math.floor( ( index ) / 5) + 1;
    var col = ( index % 5 ) + 1;
    var coord= [row,col]
    $( "span" ).text( "Coordinate: " + coord );
    $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'red' );
    //just create a new variable equal to an array. For ex: var place=[2,2] and make the cell at [2,2] turn red.
});
```

```css
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

td{
  border:1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Select a cell!</span>
<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to specify a certain matrix, you can use jQuery's eq() selector, like so:

$("tr:eq(2) td:eq(2)").css( 'background-color', 'red' );

```js
function generateGrid( rows, cols ) {
    var grid = "<table>";
    for ( row = 1; row <= rows; row++ ) {
        grid += "<tr>"; 
        for ( col = 1; col <= cols; col++ ) {      
            grid += "<td></td>";
        }
        grid += "</tr>"; 
    }
    return grid;
}

$( "#tableContainer" ).append( generateGrid( 5, 5) );

$("tr:eq(2) td:eq(2)").css( 'background-color', 'red' );
```

```css
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

td{
  border:1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Cell [2,2] automatically changed!</span>
<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the two in like a variable. Better yet, is it possible to integrate an array like [2,2] because I'd like the program to run for other arrays too

Comment: Using variables are easy... Just do this: $("tr:eq(" + myRow + ") td:eq(" + myCol + " )").css( 'background-color', 'red' ). Then you can put it in a loop or whatever.